# Server for video chat (Through manual code) - Android

Tags: android, firebase, server, video-streaming, videochat

I am working on a live random search video chat app, following the [LiveChat App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rcplatform.livechat). I have generated the search algorithms and got two Firebase Auth's Unique User_IDs(To be connected) so far, My question is that from where can i get server or maybe Library's dependencies to connect and share two user's videos, using my own manual code and ID's, please explain at a basic level.

Comment: Questions asking library or a tutorial are off-topic here

Comment: At-least give me a hint, please, i am stuck!

Comment: you will have to do it through the server. You send the video from both devices to the server and each device receives video from opposite device through the server.

Comment: Yup, and that server will be?

Comment: `and that server will be` it will be the server you are going to develop yourself